# onClick in reactjs not working

Tags: reactjs

Below is my code. My onClick is nor working. It always through error  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'likeQuestion' of undefined". But my "gotoPage" function is working. I don't know where I am wrong. I am very new in Reactjs. Why "likeQuestion" function is not recognized.

My first onClick is working

```js
export default class Question extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        pageNo : 1,
        dropdownOpen: false,
        questioninfo : []
      }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
     //some action
  }

  gotoPage(index) {

      //some action. This is working
    }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen
    });
  }

 likeQuestion(e){
    console.log('this is clicked');
    //But this is not working
 }


render() {
        var canvases = this.state.questionItem.map(function(data,i) {
          var firstLtr = data.user_name.charAt(0);

            return (
               <div key={i}>
                     <Col sm="12" md={{ size: 12, offset: 2 }} className="questionCard">
                      <Card block>
                        <CardTitle>
                                <div className="outerCircle"><span>{firstLtr}</span></div> {data.user_name}
                                <i className="fa fa-flag-o flagging" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <a href={data.location_url} target="_blank" className="questionLocation">{data.location_url}</a>
                        </CardTitle>
                        <CardText className="questionTxt">{data.message}</CardText>
                        <div>
                             <Button className="replyBtn" disabled>No Discussion</Button>
                             <Button size="sm" color="link" className="disussionSpan" onClick={(i) => this.likeQuestion(i)}>{data.likes} Likes</Button>
                        </div>
                      </Card>
                    </Col>
               </div>
            );
       });

    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
        <div className="pageInfo">
        <Dropdown className="inline" isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
          <DropdownToggle caret>
            Pages
          </DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu>
            {pgrow}
          </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
        <p className="inline currPgNo">Page: {currentPage}</p>
        </div>
            <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                {canvases}
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React wouldn't auto-bind map inside `render()`, so you have to do it yourself in order to use `this` and call `this.likeQuestion`. Luckily, map provides a second argument to specify the `context` (`this`).

---

So just use...

```
this.state.questionItem.map(function(data,i) {
  ...
}, this)
```

instead of

```
this.state.questionItem.map(function(data,i) {
  ...
})
```

- Option 2: Use arrow function in the map, such as `map((data, i) => ...`
- Option 3: bind this to `likeQuestion` in the constructor of the component.

Comment: Adding this worked cool thank you. Can you explain me why it worked?

Comment: React simply wouldn't auto-bind the map method inside render() so you have to do it yourself

Comment: glad to help;-)

Comment: can you help me on one more thing I am passing the argument which is being fetched by an api onclick is being clicked while page is loaded.

onClick={this.likeQuestion(this,data.question_url)}

Comment: You need onClick={()=>this.likeQuestion(this, data.question_url)} . Post a new question if still unclear

Comment: I tried its not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236369/onclicked-is-being-clicked-on-rendering-in-reactjs

Comment: what exactly is not working? it should work in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

Try to define your helper functions using `arrow` functions

```
 gotoPage = (index) => {

      //some action. This is working
    }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen
    });
  }

 likeQuestion = (e) => {
    console.log('this is clicked');
    //But this is not working
 }
```

or

Bind these methods in `constructor` of your React component. e.g

```
this.likeQuestion = this.likeQuestion.bind(this);
// Needs to be done for all the helper methods.
```

So that you access the class level `this` context.

E.g a minimal setup

```js
class Question extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      likes:10
    };
  }


  likeQuestion = (e) => {
    
    console.log('this is clicked');
    //But this is not working
  }
  render() {

    return ( < div >
      < button size = "sm"
      color = "link"
      className = "disussionSpan"
      onClick = {
        (i) => this.likeQuestion(i)
      } > {
        this.state.likes
      }
      Likes < /button>

          < /div >
    );
  }

};

ReactDOM.render( < Question / > , document.querySelector('#test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Updated answer with an example.

Comment: Now i m getting it right. aftr adding this in render.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you help me on one more thing I am passing the argument which is being fetched by an api onclick is being clicked while page is loaded.

onClick={this.likeQuestion(this,data.question_url)}