# onClicked is being clicked on rendering in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

So I am making API call. 
I am trying to put `"question_id"` in id of that elements where there is `className="disussionSpan"` and want to get the id onClick of that. 
I tried putting id with few characters in front that is giving me error and if i put `onClick={this.likeQuestion(this,this.state.questioninfo.question_id)}` the onClick already console the log without question_id. Again new in Reactjs
I hope I made it clear. I want to console question id on onClick.

so when I run this.
  onClick function is not been clicked and already show the console log
  I see console have already outputed

```
 - 2 this is clicked 
 - 2 this is clicked 
 - 6 this is clicked
```

This is my json response. So there are 10 total items.

```
     {
  "total_Item": 10,
  "time": "2016-12-19 16:43:23.260274",
  "Items": [
    {
      "question_url": "i-am-really-looking-fwd-to-some-new-christmas-gifts-!-when-will-they-be-added-to-the-site-724",
      "likes": 2,
      "time": "2016-11-17 03:02:36",
      "replies": [
        {
          "user_name": "Vicky",
          "message": "ihope they are added by next week?",
          "reply_id": 1650,
          "time": "2016-12-09 07:53:22"
        },
        {
          "user_name": "Siddharth Hembrom",
          "message": "test",
          "reply_id": 1670,
          "time": "2016-12-14 07:15:08"
        }
      ],
      "total_replies": 2,
      "location_url": "http://www.giftzapp.com/gifts/",
      "user_name": "Vicky",
      "message": "I am really looking fwd to some new christmas gifts ! When will they be added to the site?",
      "question_id": 724

}

export default class Question extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        pageNo : 1,
        dropdownOpen: false,
        questioninfo : [],
        questionItem: []
      }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    var url = url;
    Request.get(url)
             .then((response) => {
              this.setState({
                questioninfo: response.body,
                questionItem: response.body.Items
              })
            })
  }



  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen
    });
  }

  likeQuestion = (e) => {
      console.log('this is clicked');
      //But this is not working
   }

  render() {
      var totalPage = this.state.questioninfo.total_pages;
      var currentPage = this.state.questioninfo.current_page;


      var pgrow = [];

      for (var i = 1; i < totalPage; i++) {
          pgrow.push(<DropdownItem  onClick={this.gotoPage.bind(this, i)} key={i}>{i}</DropdownItem>);
      }
         //console.log("filter work in progress "+this.state.questioninfo.data);
        var canvases = this.state.questionItem.map(function(data,i) {
            var qid = data.question_id;
          var firstLtr = data.user_name.charAt(0);
{

            return (
               <div key={i}>
                     <Col sm="12" md={{ size: 12, offset: 2 }} className="questionCard">
                      <Card block>
                        <CardTitle>
                                    <div className="outerCircle"><span>{firstLtr}</span></div> {data.user_name}
                                    <i className="fa fa-flag-o flagging" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <a href={data.location_url} target="_blank" className="questionLocation">{data.location_url}</a>
                        </CardTitle>
                        <CardText className="questionTxt">{data.message}</CardText>
                        <div>
                              <Button className="replyBtn">
                                <Link to={`questionReply/${data.question_id}/${data.question_url}`}>
                                  {data.total_replies} Discussions
                                </Link>
                              </Button>
                             <Button size="sm" color="link" className="disussionSpan" id="likeQues{this.state.questioninfo.question_id}" onClick={this.likeQuestion(this,this.state.questioninfo.question_id)}>{data.likes} Likes</Button>
                        </div>
                      </Card>
                    </Col>
               </div>
            );
          }

       },this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of bind to send the parameters

```
onClick={this.likeQuestion.bind(this,this.state.questioninfo.question_id)}
```

and then funtion should be

```
likeQuestion = (value, e) => {
      console.log('this is clicked');
      //But this is not working
   }
```

If you don't bind, whatever you write will be executed when the element renders and hence you see the output even if you don't click

Comment: that's not the problem. the OP has bound the map function already.

Comment: @leo binding the map function will make this available to the map function and thus you can access likeQuestion like this.likeQuestion , but you still need to bind the onClick event along with the function parameters

Comment: console.log(value, 'this is clicked') should do it

Comment: this give bunch of objects but i cant find the question_id

Comment: I think a the order should be reveresed try likeQuestion = (e, value) => { console.log(value);}

Comment: I am getting undefined.

Comment: could you confirm that you get a value when you do `console.log(this.state.questioninfo.question_id);` in your map function and not undefined

Answer (score 0):

you can try with ES6 way of binding

Use an arrow function:

```
return (
  <th value={column} onClick={() => this.likeQuestion(column)}>{column}</th>
);
```

or if you want to go with ES5, then need bind in constructor as well.

```
return (
  <th value={column} onClick={that.likeQuestion.bind(that, column)}>{column}</th>
);
```

Comment: no i m getting bunch of objects of all my props and other onClick function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onClick={this.likeQuestion.bind(this,this.state.questioninfo.question_id)}

likeQuestion(a,b,c){
   console.log(a,b,c);
}
```

Check the a,b,c values.

Comment: this is clicked [object Object] undefined undefined getting this in console

Comment: use the `console.log('this.state.questioninfo.question_id', this.state.questioninfo.question_id)` inside render and check what it prints.

Comment: in state u defined questioninfo=[], then how u r accessing question_id from array ??

Comment: yeah. you are right. I cant access question id because its in questioninfo and I am only mapping questionItem

Comment: do the changes and check if the id is proper from console inside render, then it will come properly in onClick function also :)

Comment: So what i have to do? Do i have to run map on questioninfo  first den map again on questionItem ?

Comment: ques_id is different for each quest_item? you r mapping ques_items, so in onClick method you can pass `data.question_id` instead of `this.state.questioninfo.question_id` i think.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it logs out straight away is because you're essentially calling the function on render.

```
onClick={this.likeQuestion.bind(this,this.state.questioninfo.question_id)}
```

You can get around this by changing your likeQuestion method so it returns a function:

```
likeQuestion(id, e) {
  return () => {
    console.log('this is clicked', id);
  }
}
```